# Is there a site for EasyEDA?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site that covers the schematic capture software [EasyEDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyEDA)?

I cannot find any reference for help.

Answer (score 4):

There are 44 results for EasyEDA on our [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=EasyEDA) site.